# Incomplete/Inaccurate formula formation

Tags: excel, formula

My spreadsheet has a-ag columns and 100+ rows with the final row being the sum of each column.

trying to do an average if column i has text in it, than add the dollar amount is same row column n,p,q,w than divide total by number of entries in column I row 100.

In english - if column I has text in it add the number is the same row columns n,p,q,w - my question is how to add only specific cells since other cells in the same row will have numbers also

Comment: You didn't give enough info - how do you determine which specific cells you want this to run on? I think a simple `If()` would work, perhaps with `Len()`, or `Search()`?

Comment: can I upload the spread sheet to help explain...

Comment: It is preferable if you would copy and paste the data directly, then highlight everything and hit ctrl-k to format.

Comment: That did not work... so try this... =sumif(I2:i96, "<>"", (this is where i need the help, calculate numbers in same row, columns  n,q,t,w and z) than divide this total by the number of items in the sum of column I.  if there are 35 items in column I than that is the division number

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition to an [AVERAGE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6) by deconstructing it into a [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) divided by [COUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) array¹ formula.

In I12 as an array¹ formula,

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(I2:I11), I2:I11, N2:N11+P2:P11+Q2:Q11+W2:W11))/COUNTA(I2:I11)
```

[image: blah_average]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>